# How to auth user in every page with NextJS

Tags: api, rest, authentication, next.js

I have a token cookie, i want user to send a request to REST API and if success is okey user can return to page. Any thougts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a higher-order function, let's call it withAuthenticator to handle the authentication logic. Then you just need to use it in every component that needs authentication. Alternatively, just wrap withAuthenticator with your App component.

Comment: Can you give an example to that? like withRouter() but how i can write the function?

Comment: There are plenty of examples out there. For one, https://dev.to/mychal/protected-routes-with-react-function-components-dh

Comment: This example is not using higher-order function, but should give you an idea how it works.